# Is Heightened(4th) Silence spell balanced?

Tags: spells, balance, pathfinder-2e, house-rules

The second level spell [Silence can be heightened to 4th level](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=287), when its description is as follows:

> Heightened (4th) The spell effect emanates from the touched creature, silencing all sound in or passing through a 10- foot radius and preventing any auditory and sonic effects in the affected area. While within the radius, creatures are subject to the same effects as the target. Depending upon the position of the effect, a creature might notice the lack of sound reaching it (blocking off the noise coming from a party, for example).

This means that **without any saving throw** any caster that is near the target is utterly defenseless against physical attacks and unable to do any meaningful action, and this is regardless of his level.

This is because most spells have of course a verbal trait.

Just by this threat existing any wise magic user must take into account that he must have some kind of strategy to avoid such a situation and this is a very deep rabbit hole.

What I want to know is if this is taken into account in the balance of the game or if this is something that has somehow slipped in and we really should let any caster at least try to avoid the effect by adding a saving throw every turn they are inside the silence area?

Answer (score 18):

## It is balanced

Usually it just means the caster needs to Stride 2 squares. Most enemies do not have Attack of Opportunity, so you can safely do it, and even if they do have it, it is just some damage, cannot disrupt the movement.

You are in more trouble if you are Grabbed *and* Silenced, but then you can just try to get out of the Grab, most casters tend to do that anyway even without Silence, as Grab imposes a flat check on Manipulate.
I think the reason why the 2nd level version does *not* shut down spellcasting is exactly Grabs, more specifically that Freedom of Movement is only available as a 4th level spell.

And of course you have other party members, who should be able to help, by moving you, the enemy (thus ending the Grab), or casting Dispell Magic.

**Just because you cannot easily do what you usually do, it can still be balanced.

Think about Golems, they are immune to magic, should *blasters* get a saving throw?**

Comment: I don't think that it's so easy to get out of reach because to exploit the spell would be cast mainly on fighter/barbarian characters that do have AoO, and if that is the case, if you are not grabbed (which u most likely would be) at least you have to loose an action and be attacked. In alternative you would loose two actions to Step and Stride out of the silence zone leaving you with 1-action spells to cast. Not to mention that if a jolly barbarian takes 2nd level feat No Escape would literally means certain death for you.

Comment: @FrancescoRogo If you assume perfect tactics from every opponent and perfect die rolls, basically everything is "overpowered". Is Fireball overpowered if I always hit the maximum number of creatures with it and all of them have a weakness to fire? Sure. That's not going to happen often, though. And if the spell is always prepared and only used in the most optimal of circumstances, most of the time the spellcaster has just wasted a level 4 spell slot (or one spell in their repertoire if they are a spontaneous caster) because the optimal situation will not happen often.

Comment: @FrancescoRogo, as Patta said, + what if that Fighter has reach? Now you have to spend __2 actions__ to Step! The horror! As I wrote, you just take damage from a Strike, than cast  Fear on him which would cause him to flee (if we are assuming the worst outcome for everyone anyway :D )

Comment: Also of note is that a lot of caster monsters in PF2e still have the ability to be decently scary in melee without their spells. I'd not want to go toe-to-toe with a spellcaster dragon, silenced or not.

Comment: [Obligatory Order of the Stick comic link](https://i.giantitp.com//comics/oots/oots0627.gif)

Comment: I'm not assuming that everything is overpowered, that's my point. i think that THIS SPELL without a saving throw is overpowered, infact, @Patta fireball without a saving throw would be overpowered. It's not a wasted slot because it has a lot of other common uses and if you can choose between a silenced dragon and a full spell casting one i bet you would go with the silenced at the cost of a single 4th level slot.

Comment: Yes, Fireball without a save would be overpowered, because it can not be otherwise evaded. But that does not at all compare to Silence. Silence is only a 10 foot radius, which almost everyone can escape with a normal Stride. You assume optimal conditions for the Silence spell, and assume additional effects being used together with the spell (Grapple, Attacks of Opportunity etc). Under those circumstances, it is indeed "overpowered", same as a fireball that hits the max number of targets and all targets critically fail. But that's just not how the spell will work out, most of the time.

Comment: For reference, I'd consider [Blindness](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=26) to be more powerful, even with the incapacitation trait (when cast the the same level at least). It's one saving throw that, once failed, has no mitigation clause and will render far more monsters completely inept. Saying something is "balanced" is a hard claim to objectively make, but there are far stronger spells than 4th level Silence (even 4th level invisibility imo). 4th level Silence takes a planned strategy, teamwork, and a specific enemy type to be close to powerful; most spells don't.

Comment: "Fireball without a save would be overpowered" [*flammable fumes*, just over here existing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=913)

Comment: @Ifusaso a Fireball is hard enough to place, but no sane creature stays in a damaging area for a round. Flammable Fumes is ___not___ a Fireball without saves.

Comment: @Ifusaso in addition to what András said, triggering the explosion is not that easy and needs at least one, maybe multiple, additional actions and the easiest ways (using a fire effect or carrying a torch) mean you are also inside the explosion.

Comment: @ESCE i agree with you, Blindness is far more powerful and maybe difficult to avoid once you failed your saving throw. But you have a saving throw. This means that if i am of higher level than you i have a fair chance to pass, while with silence our level difference doesn't mean anything, which i consider imbalanced for a 4th level spell. Imho effects like this should be in the range of 6th level and up.

Comment: @FrancescoRogo if Silence were as deadly as you think it is, why would it be okay on any level?

Comment: @András Well, i think that the higher the spell level the higher the spell can be dangerous, it's just how it works

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, based on other 4th level spells

4th level spells give you options that:

- let you fly, negating any ground-based dangers and melee bound creatures
- Stupefy spllcasters, giving them a spell failure chance that (almost) cannot be mitigated
- Dazzle martials, giving them a Strike miss chance with very limited mitigation
- Render large swaths of battlefield dangerous to walk through or simply inaccessible

And that's just Common spells that begin with *a-c* (specifically *aerial form/air walk*, *anathematic reprisal*, *chromatic armor*, and *coral eruption*). Silence might force an enemy to make suboptimal choices if they are forced into... and it should, as a 4th level spell that lasts (probably) one conflict.

In a lot of ways, many level 4 spells are very specialized at shutting *something specific* down. *Freedom of movement* is the bane of creatures that need to grapple. *Globe of invulnerability* shuts down low level spellcasting. *Enervation* murders anything that is living. Ok, that one's less situational but I think you see what I'm getting at. A small area, even mobile, of "can't use verbal components or audible traits" is fairly on-par.

Comment: I can see your point, but somehow all your example have a caveat, something that gives the target a way to avoid the effect even if it is a slighty chance, they have one. Anyhow  as a group we decided to give it a go as it is and the future will tell.

Comment: @FrancescoRogo I guess I fail to see how "you can move out of the effect" is not a caveat

Comment: because it comes at the expense of a lot of actions. Anyway, as i said before we are using it as it is, without any house rule and we will see if it makes life just a little bit easier against spell casters as you all are saying or if it is an exploit as i fear.